# Fourier series and coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

I am struggling with the following.

> Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function with period $2\pi$ and Fourier
>   coefficients $c_n$. Prove that
>
> 1. if $f$ is in $C^k$, then $|c_nn^k|\leq M_k$, where $M_k$ is a constant independent of $n$.
> 2. if $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|c_nn^k|$ is convergent, then $f$ is in $C^k$.

For the first question, I am not sure if I can just say that $c_n(u^{(k)})=i^kn^kc_n(u)$.

For the second part, I have no idea.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To set the notation, let us define the Fourier coefficients by the following integral
\begin{align}
c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(x)e^{-in x}\ dx \ \ \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z}.  
\end{align}
Since $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, then we have that
\begin{align}
c_n =&\ \frac{-1}{2\pi in}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(x)\frac{d}{dx}e^{-in x}\ dx = \frac{-1}{2\pi in}f(x)e^{-inx}\Big|^{\pi}_{-\pi} + \frac{1}{2\pi i n}\int^\pi_{-\pi}f'(x)e^{-inx}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2\pi in} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f'(x) e^{-inx}\ dx.
\end{align}
Repeat the process $k$-times, we get
\begin{align}
c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi (in)^k} \int^\pi_{-\pi} f^{(k)}(x)e^{-inx}\ dx. 
\end{align}
Hence it following 
\begin{align}
|c_n| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi n^k} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|f^{(k)}(x)|\ dx = \frac{M_k}{n^k} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |c_n|n^k \leq M_k.
\end{align}

For the second question, let us begin by assuming 
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} |c_n|n^k<\infty.
\end{align}
By the hypothesis, we know that $f \in C^1$ and $2\pi$-periodic. Using the classical result of uniform convergence of Fourier series, then we know that
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}c_ne^{inx}
\end{align}
for all $x$.  Lastly, observe
\begin{align}
f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} c_n\frac{e^{-in(x+h)}-e^{-inx}}{h} =\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} (-inc_n) e^{-inx} \ \ (\ast)
\end{align} 
where the validity of interchanging limits in the last inequality comes from the uniform converges of the Fourier series. One should note the right-hand side series of $(\ast)$ converges uniformly since
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}|c_n|n^k<\infty. 
\end{align}

Repeat the process $k$ times will show that $f \in C^k$.